# how to show gender using simple html dom parser in php?

Tags: php, html, dom

i'm unable for success in how to show gender and state from below coading
please solve this.

```
$gender = $html->getElementById("cpBody_rbtnListGender")->getAttribute("value");
```

```
$state = $html->getElementById("cpBody_ddlState")->getAttribute("value");
```

this is for gender

```
<span id="cpBody_rbtnListGender" class="form-control pull-left radio-input"><input id="cpBody_rbtnListGender_0" type="radio" name="ctl00$cpBody$rbtnListGender" value="MALE" checked="checked" tabindex="3"><label for="cpBody_rbtnListGender_0">Male</label><input id="cpBody_rbtnListGender_1" type="radio" name="ctl00$cpBody$rbtnListGender" value="FEMALE" tabindex="3"><label for="cpBody_rbtnListGender_1">Female</label><input id="cpBody_rbtnListGender_2" type="radio" name="ctl00$cpBody$rbtnListGender" value="TRANSGENDER" tabindex="3"><label for="cpBody_rbtnListGender_2">Transgender</label><input id="cpBody_rbtnListGender_3" type="radio" name="ctl00$cpBody$rbtnListGender" value="OTHER" tabindex="3"><label for="cpBody_rbtnListGender_3">Other</label></span>
```

and this is for state

```
 <div class="input-group">
                        <label class="control-label label-fixed">State</label>
                        <select name="ctl00$cpBody$ddlState" id="cpBody_ddlState" tabindex="15" class="form-control">
    <option value="0">--SELECT STATE--</option>
    <option value="1">ANDAMAN &amp; NICOBAR ISLANDS</option>
    <option value="2">ANDHRA PRADESH</option>
    <option value="3">ARUNACHAL PRADESH</option>
    <option value="4">ASSAM</option>
    <option value="5">BIHAR</option>
    <option value="6">CHANDIGARH</option>
    <option value="7">CHHATTISGARH</option>
    <option value="8">DADRA &amp; NAGAR HAVELI</option>
    <option value="9">DAMAN &amp; DIU</option>
    <option value="10">DELHI</option>
    <option value="11">GOA</option>
    <option value="12">GUJARAT</option>
    <option value="13">HARYANA</option>
    <option value="14">HIMACHAL PRADESH</option>
    <option value="15">JAMMU AND KASHMIR</option>
    <option value="16">JHARKHAND</option>
    <option value="17">KARNATAKA</option>
    <option value="18">KERALA</option>
    <option value="19">LAKSHADWEEP</option>
    <option value="20">MADHYA PRADESH</option>
    <option value="21">MAHARASHTRA</option>
    <option value="22">MANIPUR</option>
    <option value="23">MEGHALAYA</option>
    <option value="24">MIZORAM</option>
    <option value="25">NAGALAND</option>
    <option value="26">ORISSA</option>
    <option value="27">PONDICHERRY</option>
    <option value="28">PUNJAB</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="29">RAJASTHAN</option>
    <option value="30">SIKKIM</option>
    <option value="31">TAMIL NADU</option>
    <option value="32">TELANGANA</option>
    <option value="33">TRIPURA</option>
    <option value="34">UTTAR PRADESH</option>
    <option value="35">UTTARAKHAND</option>
    <option value="36">WEST BENGAL</option>

</select>
                    </div>
```

state and gender is not showing using getAttribute("value");

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of [find](https://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.io/manual.htm).

One option to get the state could be to use the id and get the selected option `#cpBody_ddlState option[selected]`

```
$state = $html->find('#cpBody_ddlState option[selected]', 0)->plaintext;
echo $state; //RAJASTHAN
```

To get the selected radio button you might use `#cpBody_rbtnListGender input` and loop though the items until the attribute checked matches:

```
foreach ($html->find('#cpBody_rbtnListGender input') as $input) {
    if ($input->hasAttribute("checked")) {
        echo $input->getAttribute("value"); // MALE
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried its ok.

Answer (score -1):

idk why you're doing this with php.'
in javascript u can create a p to pass the value to it:

```
  <body onload="pageloaded()">
 <p id="display"></p>
```

in javascript:

```
var p = document.getElementById("display");
 var value = document.getElementById("cpBody_rbtnListGender").value;
  function pageloaded(){
  p.innerHTML = value;      
  }
```

u can do the same for ur other needs

Comment: this is also helped.